# Magento 2 - Category Image URL showing two paths

Tags: magento2.3

Bit of a strange one, but hopefully it's easy to resolve.

I have uploaded some product Category images to certain category pages in the Admin client but when I view them on the web they don't load. The reason appears to be that it is trying to load two paths in the src attribute, which are slightly different.

[image]

Any ideas what I need to do to resolve this... :-)

src="https://www.myurl.com/pub/media/catalog/category//pub/media/catalog/tmp/category/25mm.jpg"

As you can see there are two paths in the URL, one has "tmp" (in bold) and if I modify the SRC this one loads. It appears that it is prepending the URL?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

src="/pub/media/catalog/tmp/category/25mm.jpg" <- This one loads the image?

Comment: do you know how to fix it now?thank you~

Answer (score 0):

This was related to the below fix.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11995

I updated the below code on my site

file \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image.php

```
private function getUploadedImageName($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value) && isset($value[0]['file'])) {
            return $value[0]['file'];
        }
/* REMOVED 
        if (is_array($value) && isset($value[0]['name'])) {
            return $value[0]['name'];
        }
*/
        return '';
    }
```

The fact I have had to do this on a live site, on such a key part of the functionality is dumbfounding.